# Removing whitespace in textarea ignored by jQuery.trim()

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, trim, removing-whitespace

I have a `<textarea>` which contains a text called by php. The text contains an ID of the user, so it's for every user different. However, the html looks always like this:

```
<div>
    <textarea id="text" readonly="readonly">"        example text       "</textarea>
</div>
```

How do I remove these whitespaces. I have tried multiple trim suggestions or Regex approaches on SO, but none of them are working. The `textarea` cannot be changed into a `div` or `p`.

**Update:**
Regex is somehow ignored, but the below answer gave the outcome:

```
$("#text").val((i, v) => '${v.slice(1, -1).trim()}');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex pattern `/\s{2,}/g` in `.replace()` that match multiple spaces and remove them from string.

```js
$("#text").val((i, v) => v.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ''));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <textarea id="text" readonly="readonly">"        example text       "</textarea>
</div>
```

Also you can remove `"` from start and end of string using [`String.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) and then remove space using `.trim()`. At the end wrap string with `""`

```
$("#text").val((i, v) => `"${v.slice(1, -1).trim()}"`);
```

Comment: Somehow the regex examples are not working, nothing is changing and I don't see any (syntax) errors, so I am not sure why. However, your 2nd approach looks promising, only the text is being replaced with `"${v.slice(1, -1).trim()}"`. What goes wrong here?

Comment: `\`${v.slice(1, -1).trim()}\``

Comment: @Demian Both code work in snippet so maybe your selector is incorrect

Comment: @mohammad you have stated in your answer single and double quotes. Second option is working

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to remove quotes and spaces

```js
$("#text").val($("#text").val().replace(/^"\s+(.*?)\s+"$/,"$1"));
console.log(">"+$("#text").val()+"<")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <textarea id="text" readonly="readonly">"        example text       "</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: This script causes a syntax meltdown, it'c conflicting with other jQuery libraries. So it's not working. Do you have any idea what  I can do to let this regex do its job? I have tried without this library, but nothing happens

Comment: I have no clue. Are you using the text area as an editor?

Comment: No, as you can see I added the attribute readonly, It's just plain text. I am not sure why regex is not supported, probably something related with my core files.

Comment: You do not have a form plugin to pretty the form?

Comment: I would like to avoid extra plugins for this, if I can simply resolve it with a few lines of JavaScript.

Comment: That is not what I meant. I am wondering if you have a plugin that is ruining the DOM

Comment: I think a plugin is loading a jQuery library which already exists from the theme and therefore it gets ignored. I am not sure how to check for duplicate libraries, but I will contact the plugin maker to get that sorted.

Comment: Right-click on the field and choose inspect. If it is not a textarea anymore then you know

Comment: I am aware of the DevTools method, it's my daily friend. Nothing there, otherwise I'd have known.